# I need to do a search in a collection using online editor Dialogflow and Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cj1C.png)I have a question, could you guide me, please? I am practicing with Dialogflow and firebase, the topic is the following, I pass the values ​​to the agent and in the Dialogflow line editor I ask it to look for the collections that contain such ingredients and show them to me, but my code does not work, they could me help, please?

I store the ingredients in an array, the idea is to search the ingredients array and return all the possible results with such ingredients as the name of the recipe, preparation, etc.

I attach the code that I have.

```
function buscardato(agent){
let ingredients = agent.parameters.ingredients;
const Ref = db.collection('recetas');
const snapshot = Ref.where('ingredientes', '==', 'ingredients').get();
if (snapshot.empty) {
agent.add('No hay recetas con tales ingredientes.');
 return;
 }
 snapshot.forEach(doc => {
 agent.add(doc.id, '=>', doc.data() + "\n \n Dime si quieres mas recetas");
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if "ingredients" is a list, you need to use array queries such as

```
const ingredients = ["Cebolla"];
Ref.where('ingredientes', 'in', ingredients);
```

You are limited to only 10 ingredients per array however.

Comment: Thank you very much, your help was helpful